# $G$-invariant linear functions on $V \otimes \mathfrak{g}$ are $N(T)$-invariant linear functions on $V \otimes \mathfrak{h}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, representation-theory, algebraic-groups

Suppose $G$ is a reductive algebraic group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ and Cartan $\mathfrak{h} \subseteq \mathfrak{g}$ which is the Lie algebra for a torus $T \subseteq G$.

Is it true that $Hom_G(V \otimes \mathfrak{g}, \mathbb{C})$ is naturally isomorphic to $Hom_{N(T)}(V \otimes \mathfrak{h}, \mathbb{C})$ via the restriction map, for every $G$-module $V$? On the LHS we consider algebraic representations of $G$. I'm pretty sure this is equivalent to the statement that $\mathfrak{g}^*$ is isomorphic as $G$-representations to sections of the vector bundle $G \times_{N(T)} \mathfrak{h}^* \to G/N(T)$ (the induction of $\mathfrak{h}^*$ as a $N(T)$-representation to $G$, where $N(T)$ is the normalizer of $T$ in $G$).

I was thinking this might be true since it's reminiscent of the Chevalley restriction theorem which provides a graded algebra isomorphism $\mathcal{O}(\mathfrak{g})^G \to \mathcal{O}(\mathfrak{h})^W$ between rings of invariant functions on $\mathfrak{g}$ and $\mathfrak{h}$, and in particular gives us an isomorphism $Hom_G(\mathfrak{g}, \mathbb{C}) \cong Hom_W(\mathfrak{h}, \mathbb{C})$. Here $W=N(T)/T$ is the Weyl group of $T$.

Comment: So $W$ acts on $V$, and you are using the diagonal action of $W$ on $V\otimes\mathfrak{g}$?

Comment: @CharlieFrohman $W$ acts on $V$ via restriction through the $G$-action (so maybe we need to assume $T$ acts trivially, or replace $W$ with $N(T)$). And yes the action of $W$ on the tensor product is the usual one

Comment: I made an edit replacing the $W$'s in the claim with $N(T)$

Comment: This is some sort of induction. What do you tensor $\mathfrak{h}^*$ by to get $\mathfrak{g}^*$?

Comment: I’m pretty sure induction in this category is not a tensor product. The construction I know is to take sections of the bundle I wrote down above. Equivalently you can take maps $G \to \mathfrak{h}^*$ that commute with the action of $N(T)$ on $G$

Answer (score 0):

This is false. The homogeneous space $G/N(T)$ is not compact so the space of sections of the above vector bundle will be infinite-dimensional.

Comment: $X = \Bbb P^2 \backslash \{p\}$ is not compact but the vector bundle $\mathcal O_X$ has a space of sections which is finite-dimensional. So I am not sure I understand your argument.

Comment: Good point. Perhaps this argument doesn’t work at all